# How can i solve 'sdk.dir is missing' error when i build android project using ant

Tags: android, ubuntu, ant, sdk, build.xml

When I create a build.xml in command-line in window, (android update project -p . -n myapp ), then "init" , "clean" and "build" target names are basically created in build.xml.

But when creating a build.xml in ubuntu,

### following build.xml code, sdk.dir is missing.

```
<!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
     It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
     Version Control Systems. -->
<property file="local.properties" />

<!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
     'android' tool to add properties to it.
     This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
     Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

     source.dir
         The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
     out.dir
         The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

     For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
     files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

     Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
     be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

     -->
<property file="ant.properties" />

<!-- if sdk.dir was not set from one of the property file, then
     get it from the ANDROID_HOME env var.
     This must be done before we load project.properties since
     the proguard config can use sdk.dir -->
<property environment="env" />
<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>

<!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
     tool, as well as ADT.

     This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
     dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
     (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

<!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
<fail
        message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
        unless="sdk.dir"
/>

<!--
    Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
    This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
        -pre-build
        -pre-compile
        -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                       Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                       If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
        -post-package
        -post-build
        -pre-clean
-->
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

<!-- Import the actual build file.

     To customize existing targets, there are two options:
     - Customize only one target:
         - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
           <import> task.
         - customize it to your needs.
     - Customize the whole content of build.xml
         - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
           into this file, replacing the <import> task.
         - customize to your needs.

     ***********************
     ****** IMPORTANT ******
     ***********************
     In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
     in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
-->
<!-- version-tag: 1 -->
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```

Although 'command': 'ant clean' and 'ant release' are worked well,

I want additionally and automatically to create basic build.xml including 'init' ,'clean' and 'build' target names.

besides, ANDROID_HOME and PATH are already settings.

```
js@js-W65-67SH:~$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/opt/android-sdk-linux
js@js-W65-67SH:~$ 
js@js-W65-67SH:~$ echo $PATH
/home/js/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform_tools
```

---

local.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read             the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/opt/android-sdk-linux
```

I don't know how can i fix this problem.

please, help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do double check if Android SDK is downloaded in your buildbox . In your case , looks like it looks for the SDK in /opt/android-sdk-linux. So make sure it is available there.

Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System
Check "Environment variables"
add name: ANDROID_HOME, value -> The location of your Android SDK on the jenkins build box

Hit Save .

Build the job again . A local.properties file will be generated with the sdk.dir field populated.